# Sql Server select query for a special usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following SQL Server tables:

MyItemsTable (ID and LanguageId are guid's but I use here int's for easier explanation)

```
Id | Title | LanguageId
1 | My German Document 1 | 1
2 | My German Document 2 | 1
3 | My English Document 1 | 2
4 | My French Document 1 | 3
```

MyLanguagesTable

```
LanugageId | Code
1 | de-DE
2 | en-US
3 | fr-FR
```

MyItemsTable shows that there is one document (Document 1) which is available in all languages and one document (Document2) that is only in german available.

What I need now is a query which delivers all French documents and if no French document is available, then give me the german for example.

The result for French should look like:

```
My French Document 1
My German Document 2
```

The result for German should look like:

```
My German Document 1
My German Document 2
```

I think there are three things to solve:

1. Define the togetherness of the language documents (which belongs to the other but in other language)
2. Define the order if one document is not available for needed langauge. Which should be taken next. Probably making a flag on MyItemsTable when creating the first document -> IsFirst = true and when creating a language document of this first document then IsFirst = false. Taking the IsFirst = true if no document found for needed language -> something like mark the Standard document and take this if the other not available.
3. Creating a simple query which delivers all documents in german for example and if one document is not available then deliver a document in an other language.

Are there any Idea how to build up something like this in an easy way? How would you build the database tables for a simple and fast solution (MyItemsTable and MyLanguagesTable are given but can be modified)?

Thank you very much for any Ideas.

Best regards
Marc

Comment: How do you identify 2 documents being the same? Is there a link, or a common field?

Comment: No, not yet. See above "1.Define the togetherness of the language documents (which belongs to the other but in other language)". I think this depends on solution. This must be defined in a table or how ever.

Comment: Sorry missed that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should restructure your documents table to simply contain language independant data (DocumentID, Created Date, Created user document type etc),

Then have another table containing data for each language (DocumentVersion), where documentid and languageID make up a primary key:

```
DocumentID  |  LanguageID  |  Title
```

However, since your language code is a unique value for each language I would make this a natural primary key (or you could use sys.syslanguages). This is the data structure I would use for this problem:

```
CREATE TABLE Document
(       DocumentID      INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Document_DocumentID PRIMARY KEY,
        DefaultTitle    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        CreatedDate     DATETIME NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Language]
(       LanguageCode    CHAR(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Lanaguage_LanguageCode PRIMARY KEY,
        Name            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        Alias           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.DocumentVersion
(       DocumentFK      INT NOT NULL,
        LanguageCode    CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        Title           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_DocumentVersion PRIMARY KEY (DocumentFK, LanguageCode)
    CONSTRAINT FK_DocumentVersion_LanguageCode FOREIGN KEY (LanguageCode) REFERENCES dbo.[Language] (LanguageCode),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DocumentVersion_DocumentID FOREIGN KEY (DocumentFK) REFERENCES dbo.Document (DocumentID)
);
INSERT Document (DefaultTitle, CreatedDate) 
VALUES 
    ('Document 1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
    ('Document 2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT dbo.[Language] (LanguageCode, Name, Alias)
VALUES 
    ('de-DE', 'Deutsch', 'German'), 
    ('en-US', 'US English', 'English'),  
    ('fr-FR', 'Français', 'French');

INSERT dbo.DocumentVersion (DocumentFK, LanguageCode, Title) 
VALUES
    (1, 'de-DE', 'My German Document 1'),
    (2, 'de-DE', 'My German Document 2'),
    (1, 'en-US', 'My English Document 1'),
    (1, 'fr-FR', 'My French Document 1')
```

In order to get the documents in the way you said you would need a custom case statement to get the right order by. So with the above sample you could use

```
DECLARE @PrimaryLanguage CHAR(5) = 'fr-FR',
        @DefaultLanguage CHAR(5) = 'de-DE';

WITH RankedDocument AS
(   SELECT  DocumentFK, 
            LanguageCode, 
            Title,
            SortOrder = CASE WHEN LanguageCode = @PrimaryLanguage THEN 1 
                            WHEN LanguageCode = @DefaultLanguage THEN 2
                            -- MORE SORTING CRITERIA IF REQURED
                            ELSE 10
                        END
    FROM    DocumentVersion
), Docs AS
(   SELECT  d.DocumentID,
            rd.Title,
            d.CreatedDate,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.DocumentID ORDER BY rd.SortOrder)
    FROM    Document d
            INNER JOIN RankedDocument rd
                ON d.DocumentID = rd.DocumentFK
)
SELECT  DocumentID, Title, CreatedDate
FROM    Docs
WHERE   rn = 1;
```

**[Example with French Documents](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c732d/4)**

**[Example with German Documents](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c732d/5)**

**EDIT**

To do this with your current structure you need to add a field to `MyItemsTable`, this should Probably be a foreign key to a new table, for demonstration sake I have just used `LinkField`:

```
DECLARE @PrimaryLanguage INT = 1,
        @DefaultLanguage INT = 1;

WITH RankedItem AS
(   SELECT  ID, 
            Title, 
            LanguageId, 
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LinkField ORDER BY CASE LanguageId 
                                                                                WHEN @PrimaryLanguage THEN 1
                                                                                WHEN @DefaultLanguage THEN 2 
                                                                                ELSE 10 
                                                                            END)
    FROM    MyItemsTable
)
SELECT  ID, Title, LanguageID
FROM    RankedItem
WHERE   rn = 1;
```

**[Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e37833/7)**

Comment: Is this possible without the DocumentVersion separated? I need to use the MyItemsTable only?

Comment: Why do you need to do it only with MyItemsTable? You at the very least need a further field in MyItemsTable to identify similar documents, are you able to add a field to this table? Ultimately almost anything is possible, but just because something is possible does not mean it is the way to solve a problem.

Comment: Every item in MyItemsTable is an own document. Every field belongs to the item itself and can be different to other language items. A German document has an id, title, Content, createdby etc. and the english document has it's own fields. I can insert a new field of course for holding the different language items together, that would be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you should have a table for all documents independant of language, then have a table of languages (i would suggest using the iso value for each language: this is pretty comprehensive, as there is also a value for klingon) then you need a many to many table (which is actually a combination of two one to many relationships) each table should have clustered indexes, primary and foreign keys, and covering indexes for potential queries. If any of these terms is new to you, the google is your friend as is http://www.w3schools.com/sql/. The solution when constructed with these constraints will fully impiment the power of  realtional (SQL) database

Comment: Yes, I think it's clear so far but I don't know how you would deliver a French document for example if the german is not available. How would you do this?

Comment: I think GarethD's code does this, if you combine these two answers: I have provided the overview, however I feel the most important thing is to understand the approach rather than the detail. The art behind SQL is determining the relational structure. the first part is to determin the truely independant "objects" in this case languages and books, then the relationship between them. Then the indexes so that all runs smoothly. Once you have done this there is syntax within SQL to allow you to combine results in almost any way you can express in english.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to add a Column that specify the doc type means for similar document. 
so in my case its DOC_TYPE_ID

Now for using following query to just send LANGUAGE_ID i.e. (1, 2, 3)

---

> DECLARE @LANGUAGE_ID INT
>
> SET @LANGUAGE_ID = 1;  (change value 1 for German, 3 for French and 2
>   for English)
>
> WITH T (ID, DOC_TYPE_ID, TITLE, LANGUAGE_ID, DOCUMENT_RECORD_COUNT) 
>   AS (
>
> SELECT d.ID, d.DOC_TYPE_ID, d.TITLE, d.LANGUAGE_ID,   DENSE_RANK() OVER
>   (PARTITION BY d.DOC_TYPE_ID ORDER BY d.LANGUAGE_ID  DESC) AS
>   DOCUMENT_RECORD_COUNT  FROM [Document] d
>   WHERE 1 = (CASE WHEN @LANGUAGE_ID = 3 THEN CASE WHEN d.LANGUAGE_ID IN
>   (1, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
>                     WHEN @LANGUAGE_ID = 2 THEN CASE WHEN d.LANGUAGE_ID IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
>                     WHEN d.LANGUAGE_ID = @LANGUAGE_ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
>                )

) SELECT  ID, DOC_TYPE_ID, TITLE, LANGUAGE_ID, DOCUMENT_RECORD_COUNT

> FROM T  WHERE DOCUMENT_RECORD_COUNT = 1 ORDER BY DOC_TYPE_ID

Comment: That looks absolutely great for LanugageId 1 and 3. But for english LanguageId=2 the "My German Document 2" should appear as well. Do you have any idea?

Comment: check again..i have modified it.

Comment: That's just great! What is the ..DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY.. exactly for?

Comment: when we want to assign a sequential order, or rank for our records.

Comment: This works fine but I don't understand what is going on exactly. If I add another language f.e. italian LanugageId=4

Comment: If you dont need that next language with another one, e.g. you added italian(4) and you want to get italian and english when passing 4 as parameter then you have to append in where clause. But is there not confirm that how many languages and if languages added day by day with the documents then you have to made little bit changes in your db structure.

Comment: Sorry here my fully post...This works fine but I don't understand what is going on exactly. If I add another language f.e. italian LanugageId=4 how does it looks like? Why "1, 3" in here ...WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 3 THEN CASE WHEN d.LANGUAGE_ID IN (1, 3)? Is this an order? Why is the 2 not in it? If there are 4 languages does it look like ...WHEN LANGUAGE_ID = 4 THEN CASE WHEN d.LANGUAGE_ID IN (1, 4)? If you can explain your solution a bit, that would be very nice...it's great and exactly what I need. I would like to understand it better. Thanx a lot.

Comment: you said in your post that "What I need now is a query which delivers all French documents and if no French document is available, then give me the german for example. so you call french docs (3) if its not available then it brings english (1)... so

Comment: How does it looks like when I need French, but french and english is not available? It should take the german one then. Is it then include the 2 like ...WHEN @LANGUAGE_ID = 3 THEN CASE WHEN d.LANGUAGE_ID IN (1, 2, 3) THEN.. Is this correct?

Comment: You need to modify your language table as

LANGUAGE_ID,
CODE,
TITLE,
SUPPORTING_LANGUAGE_IDS  ( this will be csv )

and record will be as 
1   Fr       French      1,2,3
2   Gr       German      2,3
3   En       English     1,3

so now will be easy to get your required results..